# WinForms ListBox Right-Click

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, contextmenu, right-click

I am trying to add a context menu to a listbox when you right click an item.

I am not even sure if the right click function with working properly.

Here is the code:

```
private void lstSource_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Right Click");
    }
}
```

Nothing prints to the console. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your application have a console? Perhaps try to show a MessageBox instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you wire the event up (and the ListBox is enabled):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(listBox1_MouseDown);
}

void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Right Click");
  }
}
```

You can also have the designer wire up the event for you by selecting the ListBox and double-clicking on the MouseDown event in the Properties window (click on the lightning bolt).

Answer (score 2):

`Console.WriteLine()` method wont display anything on GUI. Use `MessageBox.Show("Right Click");`

```
private void lstSource_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Right Click");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Be sure that the handler is attached with `MouseDown` event or not.